# Execute javascript after reactjs render method has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have a reactjs component:

```
var com1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (  
    <a href='#'>This is a text</a>
    );
  }
});
```

I want to execute Javascript/Jquery once rendering of this componenet has completed. Simply adding Javascript to the render method doesn't seem to work.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: i guess you can use `com1.promise().done(fn)`.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate please, I'm new to reactjs and am now sure what you mean. Where would I put this code for example and I assume "fn" could take any javascript (e.g. alert("test"))?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [componentDidMount](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) method to run code after initial render and [componentDidUpdate](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) to run code after each update of component's state.

Comment: From my own experience - you also need to add a setTimeout(foo, 1) method inside the 'componentDidMount', so that the elements that react renders actually show in the real dom.

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

In the component lifecycle, you can define a callback for componentDidMount -- i.e., the render function has completed and the resulting elements have been inserted into the DOM.